# How do I rewrite the \listoftables command to allow for different sized table names?

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, renewcommand

I'm trying to make it so that in the list of figures (and tables), I have the figure number behind "Figure". So, I want it to have

Figure 1.1 ............description............... pagenumber

The issue is that currently it has:

1.1 ............description............... pagenumber

I finally figured out how to add in the Figure into the .cls file by simple adding:

```
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{Figure. \arabic{chapter}. \arabic{figure} }
\renewcommand{\thetable}{Table. \arabic{chapter}. \arabic{table} }
```

This works but the .cls file that I'm working with doesn't seem to like the addition of the extra word in there. As such, it looks like:

[image]

Hopefully that makes sense. Basically it doesn't leave enough space for the Figure and so the description overwrites on the Figure.

Ultimately, what I want to do is to simply make it so that my list of figures has the literal word "figure" in front of the number(which is the default). How do I do that?

As a bonus, I also have some issue with appendix tables/figures. Since I'm using the renewcommand shown above, it causes the appendix tables to be defaulted to 1.1 even though I want A.1, etc.

I also attached a snippet of the .cls file I'm using right now. Hopefully that counts as a MWE?

```
  \if@twocolumn
    \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
  \else
    \@restonecolfalse
  \fi
  \begingroup
    \@frontmattertitle{\listtablename}% name on toc
    \addcontentsline{toc}{schapter}{\listtablename}    

    %\typeout{Look here: fnum: \fnum@table  csname: \csname fnum1}
     %fnum@#1 fnum2 fnum@#2 }
    \noindent \hfill PAGE
    \par
    \ssp % so that single entries are singlespaced
    \@starttoc{lot}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
  \endgroup
  \newpage
}
```

Comment: An MWE would allow somebody else to reproduce the output you show in order to debug. Nobody can look at the problem but you right now. So anybody answering has to guess what you are actually doing and, as you've discovered, that can lead to solutions which don't work well for you. (To be fair, this is possible anyway; it is just many times more probable without an MWE.)

Answer (score 0):

Don't fiddle with the `.cls` file, whatever that might be but use the `tocloft` package.

```
% lofprob.tex  SE 619608

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{4em} % Extra space for figure number
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Figure } % put Figure before number

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\begin{figure}
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Read the `tocloft` package documentation for more information; it also deals with table entries in a LoT.

Comment: It seems that is the way to go if I were just starting out, but it also completely breaks a number of other things. I don't have a listoftables entry in the TOC, I don't have the page numbers flushright, etc. I simply wanted to see if I can increase "numwidth" without the use of an extra package.

Comment: @RexLam OK leave the `.cls` file as is but use the `tocloft` package as I did with the `article` class.

Comment: @RexLam But maybe your `.cls` file is incompatible with `tocloft`.